# How do I create a picklist of option in the design attribute of my lightning flow component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I want to have a picklist of options in the config settings of my lightning flow component. Then I can read the chosen option and execute different code depending on flow component settings at flow screen design time.

[image]

It shows the variable but not as a picklist of options. If I try to change the components (cmp) attribute type from type="string" to type="string[]" as I've seen in some posts, I get the following error.
"Only String attributes may have a datasource in the design file."

Compoment .cmp

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="lbl" type="String" default="No Label"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pList" type="String" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selOpt" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div>
        {!v.lbl}<br/>
        Chosen Design Option: {!v.selOpt}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Design File .design

```
<design:component label="Flow Component Test">
    <design:attribute name="lbl" label="Label"/>
    <design:attribute name="pList" datasource="Option 1,Option 2,Option 3"/>
</design:component>
```

Controller .js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selOpt = component.get('v.pList');
        component.set('v.selOpt',selOpt);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<aura:attribute name="pList" type="string" access="global"/>
```

Should be:

```
<aura:attribute name="pList" type="String" access="global"/>
```

Aura is case sensitive, so you must make sure that you are using the correct casing for attribute types (e.g. `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, or `Object` rather than `object`).

Comment: already tried that. Still doesn't turn the design element on the screen flow component into a picklist with the options specified in the datasource. Doesn't even offer them as selections